# Read file from sys.stdin in 'rb' mode : Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have written below code to convert a csv file to a xml file. I am reading the file from sys.stdin and writing the output back to sys.stdout. I am getting below error while reading a file.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 7652: invalid continuation byte

I have researched the error and found that reading the input file in 'rb' mode may resolve the error. Now how do I change the below code to read the input file from sys.stdin in 'rb' mode. I could not find answer yet.

```
import csv
import sys
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

filename = sys.argv[1]
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]+'.xml'
pathname = "/tmp/"
output_file = pathname + filename

f = sys.stdin
reader = csv.reader(f)
fields = next(reader)
fields = [x.lower() for x in fields]
fieldsR = fields

doc = Document()
dataRoot = doc.createElement("rowset")
dataRoot.setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
dataRoot.setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', "./schema.xsd")
doc.appendChild(dataRoot)

for line in reader:
    dataElt = doc.createElement("row")           
    for i in range(len(fieldsR)):
        dataElt.setAttribute(fieldsR[i], line[i])
        dataRoot.appendChild(dataElt)


xmlFile = open(output_file,'w')
xmlFile.write(doc.toprettyxml(indent = '\t'))
xmlFile.close()
sys.stdout.write(output_file)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3 code? If it's Python 3, switching to binary mode is easy, but also not the answer; the `csv` module requires `str` inputs.

Comment: It is Python 3. Input is a normal csv file thru sys.stdin. Which has data in text not in binary. Can you please elaborate how to resolve it in code.

Comment: The problem isn't the code, it's your input or your locale. Your locale settings are saying input is expected to be UTF-8; the actual data being passed to `sys.stdin` is in some other encoding (no way to know from the error; the `file` command line utility on UNIX-likes might be able to tell you if the data is being piped from a file on disk). The locale encoding and file encoding need to agree so the raw bytes can be decoded to the logical text they're supposed to represent.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, both stdin, stout and stderr are wrapped in IO buffers that apply on the fly text encoding/decoding to the streams.

If you want direct access to the underlying binary stream, it is available as attributes in these wrappers.

For stdin, instead of calling `.read` in `sys.stdin` do `sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read()` -
(and likewise for stderr and stdout, just use `...buffer.raw` to get to the underlying binary stream).